# how to delete property from object

Tags: python, properties

If I have a property like `bpy.types.Object.thing = BoolProperty()` how would I go about removing it? I have tried `del bpy.context.object.thing` and `bpy.context.object.remove("thing")` and `del bpy.context.object["thing"]`. Do I just have to create a new object with this objects data? Or is there a way to delete them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first command adds a new property to `bpy.types.Object` as in your altering the base class used for all objects. The next steps you are trying to remove a custom property from an individual object instance.

To add and remove a property from all objects -

```
bpy.types.Object.thing = bpy.props.BoolProperty()
del bpy.types.Object.thing
```